# I am getting io not defiend error in my socket.io client

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, socket.io

This is my server side code for creating connection to the socket.I am using node.js code and using socket.io in that.

```
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketIO(server);


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('New user connected');


})
```

and this is my client side code i am using plain javascript as a client and I am using 2.1.1 version of socket.io, I am getting io not defiend error,I am very new to socket.io please help me one this one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

  </head>
  <body>

    <script>

 $(document).ready(function(){
   var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
        console.log("Socket connected"+socket.connected);

        socket.on('notification', function(value){
            //insert your code here
        });
});


    </script>


        <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>



     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first script (the one using `io`) is running before your other scripts (the jQuery and Socket scripts). Move your scripts around like so:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
    console.log("Socket connected" + socket.connected);

    socket.on('notification', function(value) {
      //insert your code here
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I'm new to web development this might be wrong, but I would try to place your script below the script where you import socket.io.js

In your function you are calling io but before you call it it doesn't seem to be declared.

Hope this works.